# I'm getting error: We don't support cucumber version 7, in angular protractor automation project

Tags: angular, automation, protractor, cucumber

I need help, I'm running ng e2e, I install the types chai and cucumber, also I installed the version 7 of cucumber.

protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
 allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
specs: [
'./src/features/**/*.feature'
],
capabilities: {
 'browserName': 'chrome'
},
cucumberOpts: {
require: ['./src/steps/**/*.steps.ts'],
},
directConnect: true,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
onPrepare() {
require('ts-node').register({
  project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
});
}
};
```

tsconfig.e2e.json

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "types": ["chai", "cucumber", "node"]
 }
}
```

Error in terminal:
[image: Error in terminal:]

Answer (score 2):

first, uninstall your cucumber versions

> 1. npm uninstall cucumber
> 2. npm uninstall @cucumber/cucumber

then install an older version of cucumber

> npm install cucumber@6.0.5

Working for me let here now if face any other issue

Answer (score 0):

Do not install cucumber separately. Use cucumber that is bundled inside protractor-cucumber-framework.

Comment: But I'm following a guide to use that framework and I have to install cucumber with npm -g cucumber

Comment: @Xotabu4, what one wants to use newer version than the included? Would this mean impossible?